# How can I prevent a field from displaying on a ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, pinax

In a project I'm working on, I have:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.BazField()

class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        exclude = ('bar')
```

The page displaying the ModelForm is displaying the field bar even though I don't want it to.

What, besides placing the Foo field name at the beginning of FooForm's `exclude` list, can I do so that the ModelForm-based page does not display the label and field for **bar**?

Thanks,

Comment: Make it a tuple `exclude = ('bar', )` (missed the trailing `,`)

Comment: That was a copyist error on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exclude expects a tuple or list (one element in parenthesis without a comma, as you currently have it, isn't treated as a tuple).

Try either

```
exclude = ('bar',)  # with the comma so its treated as a tuple
```

or

```
exclude = ['bar']  # less ambiguous
```